# Sorting a QListWidget by numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I have a `QListWidget` with these items:

```
1
10
100
11
110
111
12
```

And I want to order the items of the list by numbers:

```
1
10
11
12
100
110
111
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `QListWidget` will order the elements with respect to the text, if you want to be ordered with respect to the numeric value that is associated with the text you must create a custom `QListWidgetItem` and overwrite the method `__lt__`:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class ListWidgetItem(QListWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        try:
            return float(self.text()) < float(other.text())
        except Exception:
            return QListWidgetItem.__lt__(self, other)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QListWidget()
    for i in [1, 10, 100, 11, 110, 111, 12]:
        w.addItem(ListWidgetItem(str(i)))
    w.sortItems()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```